# movegroup eigen error when doing pick

Tags: ros, eigen3, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ubuntu 14.04 trusty

ros indigo

as soon as my pick place node reaches pick the movegroup launch terminal gives this error :

```
[ INFO] [1410435960.615041253]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
move_group: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:78: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = double; int Size = 16; int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(eigen_unaligned_array_assert_workaround_gcc47(array)) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.
[move_group-1] process has died [pid 6922, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group __name:=move_group __log:=/home/jaysin/.ros/log/d4d874c0-39a8-11e4-a0cf-28e347742258/move_group-1.log].
log file: /home/jaysin/.ros/log/d4d874c0-39a8-11e4-a0cf-28e347742258/move_group-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

i have gcc 4.8 installed and have been to the mentioned website, but not being too confident about what to do, i would like to know if there is a simple fix for this, and if no simple fix is available then what course of action i should take?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192477/movegroup-eigen-error-when-doing-pick/) by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2014-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an instance of a Eigen alignment issue that can occur on systems where data is not properly aligned in memory, which means vectorization won´t work. Read the [link](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html)  stated in the error message for some further info. You´ll find quite a few other questions regarding this here on ROS Answers , too.

This issue can generally be fixed by modifying source code, but depending on the issue at hand this might not be trivial. Luckily, this error only appears on 32bit (x86) systems, so a relatively easy solution to get rid of it is switching to a 64bit Ubuntu version (not sure about architectures like ARM and others).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) on 2014-09-12**:
would switching to gcc-4.6 and then compiling solve things?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-09-12**:
Pretty sure it would not. I´d recommend installing a 64bit system if at all possible, as this takes a relatively short time and is sure to fix the problem.